# Typo3 Workspace elements not shown in preview

Tags: typo3, workspace, typo3-10.x

First foremost: I am aware that this is not a general Typo3 bug/error per se, as I have working installations. I am hoping for hints/help in finding the error in this installation, as it's way too big to just set it up as a new installation.

I have an erronous Typo3 10.4.17 installation (updated to 10.4.x, no fresh install)
Problem: Edited elements in workspace are not shown in the Frontend preview (opened via "Show webpage" or other basic means in BE) nor in the BE View-module.
Additional info #1: They are however shown when preview links are generated via "Generate page preview links" and those are viewed.
Additional info #2: Changed elements only become visible after publishing them & clearing Cache
Additional info #3: Clearing any Cache does not make them visible in the preview

After comparing all settings I could think of to another working installation I decided to delve into the core in search for a hint/solution and got stuck there at following point:

TYPO3\CMS\Workspaces\Controller\PreviewController
Line 130 $workspaceItemsArray = $this->workspaceService->selectVersionsInWorkspace()
As well as:
TYPO3\CMS\Workspaces\Service\WorkspaceService
Line 220 public function selectVersionsInWorkspace()
At this point my edited workspace version of the element does get retrieved. selectVersionsInWorkspace() does get called when viewing the preview.
While the PreviewController does not further filter the staged elements, they are not displayed in the Preview.

I am looking for any hint as to where selectVersionsInWorkspace() might still be filtered or other hints as to possible reasons/solutions for this problem that I may have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Just when I decided to post to SO a co-worker found the reason...
As it's a big installation we use a dev-domain as admins and each website (over 100) have their own domains which are also set as base in the Site-config.
Only when the preview is opened as either the base or a baseVariant the workspace-elements are displayed at all. In older version the elements would still be displayed when opened via other associated domains, just sometimes not 100% accurately.
Letting this stay in case anyone ever has a similar problem and is hopefully able to find this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Had the same problem on a big website. This saved me. Adding a site configuration for the preview URL did the job.